# Programmatically find unused Linux IP route table ID?

Tags: linux, routing, iproute

As part of a script, I'd like to temporarily add a route table for the duration of the script.

```
ip route add default via "${ip}" dev "${dev}" table "${table}"
.
.
.
ip route flush table "${table}"
```

If there a good way to programmatically find an unused table ID to use for this purpose?

Answer (score 2):

```
i=1
while [ "$(ip route show table "$i")" ]; do i=$((i+1)); done
# $i is your free table
```

some shell wizard may make it better ;-)